# NullPointerException when calling registerOutputParamater on CallableStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ejb, weblogic

In my application I use a Stored Procedure, called `SearchSubscriptionData`, to lookup a number in two different subscription tables.

Database is accessed via a JDBC Configuration (MySQL drivers) on WebLogic 10.3.3. I only use one user (root, no password).

The code snippet that I use is:

```
Connection con = getConnection(); // perform lookup on JDBC Driver
CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall("{CALL SearchSubscriptionData(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
cst.setString("numTel", aBnumber); // input param (B-Number)
cst.registerOutParameter("numberFoundFlag", Types.INTEGER); 
cst.registerOutParameter("radixFound", Types.VARCHAR); // <-- this instruction generates a NullPointerException
cst.registerOutParameter("outRoutingId", Types.VARCHAR);
...// plus three more parameters, not important now
```

Exception is:

```
[#|2013-09-16T14:35:51.340+0200|SEVERE|ece|com.ericsson.core.db.DBManager|_ThreadID=451;_ThreadName=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default(self-tuning)';ClassName=com.ericsson.core.db.DBManager;MethodName=searchSubscriptionData;_RequestID=<unavailable>|Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.getNamedParamIndex(CallableStatement.java:1250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1668)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.CallableStatement_com_mysql_jdbc_CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(Unknown Source)    
    at com.ericsson.core.db.DBManager.searchSubscriptionData(DBManager.java:139)
    at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.screening.service.Screening.getSubscriptionDataWithStoreProcedure(Screening.java:2481)
    at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.screening.service.Screening.onInitialDP(Screening.java:1463)
    at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.screening.service.Screening.handleMessage(Screening.java:384)
    at com.ericsson.cba.cs1plus.traffic.impl.CallSession.dispatchEvent(CallSession.java:1303)
    at com.ericsson.cba.cs1plus.traffic.impl.CallSession.doInitialDpEvent(CallSession.java:537)
    at com.ericsson.cba.cs1plus.traffic.impl.CallSession.doHandleNetworkEvent(CallSession.java:331)
    at com.ericsson.cba.cs1plus.traffic.impl.CallSession.handleMessage(CallSession.java:234)
    at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.screening.service.Screening.handleEvent(Screening.java:327)
    at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.services.screening.service.Screening.onCreate(Screening.java:236)
    at com.ericsson.ngin.session.mdb.DefaultServiceMDB.onCreate(DefaultServiceMDB.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor677.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[...more stack trace here...]
```

Does anyone see anything familiar here? Important to highlight that the same error happens if the stored procedure is removed from MySQL DB, like if the error would be an access error to store procedure itself: but which kind of error?

What is indeed strange to me is why the `NullPointerException` applies to "second" `registerOutParameter` call and not to the first one already.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure 'radixFound' is the correct OUT parameter name?

Comment: Yeah... sounds like you have a bad name or a bad type to cast it to.

Comment: `CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE SearchSubscriptionData (
    IN numTel varchar(28),
    OUT numberFoundFlag int,
    OUT radixFound varchar(28), 
    OUT outRoutingId varchar(28), 
    OUT outNpStatus int,
    OUT outAlertMonitoring int, 
    OUT outVideoCallAllowed int)
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER`  This is the way the SearchSubscriptionData stored procedure is created in MySQL DB. The name radixFound is actually correct. I have also done a little java client that accesses such store procedure via JDBC, and works well with the same code as in the EJB. Weblogic config issue, maybe?

Comment: Instead of binding by name, try index e.g. `cst.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);`

Comment: Issue actually solved deleting entry in the table, and recreated via dos prompt command line instead of using Toad (MySQL tool) as I did first time. For some reason entering a record in table using Toad has created this strange issue. What is worst at the end was that I was not even capable to reproduce this problem re-doing the same sequence of operation. Annoying! Thanks for your help guys, anyway. Pierluigi